# How to show nested custom dataset in Civicrm Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, civicrm

I have installed civicrm in drupal 7 set up. Now as per my client's requirement i have to show one custom dataset into another custom dataset. For. eg. One custom dataset as "Medical" and with in that one or more custom dataset of "Doctors", "Diagnosis" etc should be displayed. Also, the display of them should be like the 'Summary' tab of civicrm layout.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 possibilities :

- you use CiviCase that will allow you to create several cases (i.e. Medical) for a CiviCRM contact and add Activities in them (Diagnosis) and contacts (Doctors). You can create custom activities type and add custom fields to it. It's the only solution i see with no need to develop so this would be my recommendation.
- you develop this functionnality with Drupal entities, create links to CiviCRM contact with [CiviCRM User Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_user_reference) and find a way to display it in CiviCRM using [hook_civicrm_tabs](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tabs)
- you develop an extension in CiviCRM that create new tables with the data you need or leverage custom fields and display the information the way you want. I have published a [simple extension](https://github.com/coopsymbiotic/coop.symbiotic.tabpanel) that i want to improve to make it work like summary tabs in CiviCRM. It could be a starting point for you but probably not because you need something quite different.